# Why doesn't my custom callback in Passport JS work?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm trying to get the user to be able to sign up to my website, and store the credentials on mongodb.

This is my auth.js file, where the route is defined:

```
router.post('/signup', (req,res,next) => {
    Passport.authenticate('local-signup', err => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.name === "MongoError" && err.code === 11000) {
            res.status(409).json({
                success: false,
                message: "Unsuccessful",
                errors: {
                    email: "This email is already taken."
                }
            });
        }
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Unsuccessful",
            errors: {
                unknown: "Could not process for some reason. Contact admin."
            }
        });
    }        
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Successful",
        errors: {}
    });
}) (res, req, next);
}
```

That last bracket got a bit messed up but believe me, it's not a syntax error. 
This snippet is where I have defined the passport strategy:

```
require ('../Models/Users')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/onlinestore');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const PassportLocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const Passport = require('passport');

module.exports = Passport.use(new PassportLocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        session: false,
        passReqToCallback: true,
    }, (email, password, done) => {              
        let user = new User();
        user.email = email.trim();
        user.password = password.trim();
        user.save(err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return done(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Success");
                return done(null);
            }
        });
    }
));
```

The route is able to get the user inputted password and user. When I click submit, literally nothing happens; the server doesn't console anything nor does the client. After a bit of debugging I think the issue is due to the fact that Passport.Authenticate is not being called but I'm not sure why. I can post other code snippets if necessary, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is OP. I was able to find the solution.
1) In my auth.js file,

```
Passport.authenticate('local-signup', err => {
```

replace the 'local-signup' with 'local'
so it becomes:

```
Passport.authenticate('local', err => {
```

2) I happened to have multiple Passport strategies and each are in their own file, (one for login and one for signup). To use the correct "local" I have to import the correct one in my auth.js file. Easy enough, it's

```
const passport = require('../Passport/local-signup');
```

For login, it would be a different file.